# Pass variable to method info_for_paper_trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, paper-trail-gem

Into the table versions I created new column 'localip' .
In view I have hidden field where I put value via JS:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :localIP, :value => params[:localIP] %>
```

If I understand correctly the paper_trail is called as first, so I put in my controller:

```
  prepend_before_action :set_localip, only: :update   

  def info_for_paper_trail
     { 
       :ip => request.remote_ip, 
       :agent => request.user_agent,
       :localip => @localip
      }
  end

private
    def set_localip
       @localip = params[:localIP] 
    end
```

but during update :localip is not passed:

```
PaperTrail::Version Create (0.3ms) INSERT INTO "versions" ("item_type", "item_id", "event", "whodunnit", "object", "created_at", "object_changes", "ip", "agent") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

do anybody know how to pass such value?

Comment: Can you double-check that your `versions` table actually has a `localip` column? Maybe you forgot to run the migration?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

*in Controller:*

```
  prepend_before_action :set_localip, only: :update   
  before_action :set_paper_trail_whodunnit, if: :user_signed_in?

  def info_for_paper_trail
     { 
       :ip => request.remote_ip, 
       :agent => request.user_agent,
       :localip => @localip
      }
  end#

private
    def set_localip
       @localip = params.require(:commission)[:localIP]
    end
```

*/config/initializers/paper_trail.rb*

```
module PaperTrail
  class Version < ::ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :whodunnit
  end
end
```